# Extra padding with @font-face in Windows?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, operating-system, font-face

I have come across an issue with Windows rendering of an Font Squirrel @fontface font ([Lekton Regular](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lekton)).

In Chrome and Firefox it renders perfectly:

[image]

But in the same browsers in Windows (XP and 8 tested), it adds top and bottom padding:

[image]

The computed styles for both elements are the same across both browsers, on both operating systems.

Is this a known issue and is there a work around?

Comment: It could be something to do with the `line-height` for the font, I have found when I use @font-face I sometimes have to mess with it to make them work

Comment: you can  use firebug to see weather its padding or line height

Comment: line-height doesn't help, just moves the padding. Margin and Padding already explicitly set to 0px

Comment: Please post the relevant code (HTML and CSS).

Comment: As it's all identical, I don't know what you hope to learn from it

Comment: Can you at least share a link where the problem can be inspected?

Comment: I have answered the issue now. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the font file. The problem disappeared when I loaded an alterative (from Google Fonts)